# To import data from file to existing workbook using Vlookup

Tags: vba, excel

I have a main workbook and a sub workbook that macro commands to open

1) Main workbook = Database
 
Worksheet in Main Workbook = Customer database
Sub workbook = Orders

These two books are open for macro to run.

1) I need to import data `Range C:F` from `Orders` to `Customer Database B:E` if `Cell B` from `Orders` contains `New Member`

2) The worksheet in database already contains data. Hence, I want it to add on to the existing sheet in `Database`

Please help.

```
Dim wsSource As Worksheet
Dim wbSource As Workbook
Dim wsTarget As Worksheet
Dim wbTarget As Workbook
Dim findRange As Range
Dim lastline As Integer
Dim file As String

file = "Orders.xlsx"
Set wbSource = ThisWorkbook
Set wsSource = wbSource.Sheets(1)
Set wbTarget = Workbooks.Open(file)
Set wsTarget = wbTarget.Sheets(1)

wsTarget.Activate

Set findRange = wsTarget.Range("C2:F389")
findRange.Replace What:="xxx-string",Replacement:=wsSource.Range("b2:e2").Value, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False

lastline = wbSource.Sheets(1).Range("X65536").End(xlUp).Row

Dim d As Integer
Dim j As Integer


d = 3
j = 2

For b = 1 To lastline
    If wsTarget.Range("B" & j) = "New Member" Then
        d = d + 1
        wsSource.Range("B" & j).Value = wsTarget.Range("C" & d).Value
        wsSource.Range("C" & j).Value = wsTarget.Range("D" & d).Value
        wsSource.Range("D" & j).Value = wsTarget.Range("E" & d).Value
        wsSource.Range("E" & j).Value = wsTarget.Range("F" & d).Value
    End If
    j = j + 1
Next b
```

Comment: WHYT - What have you tried? If you have difficulties in your attemps to solve your problem, please elaborate those.

Comment: I am not sure how to input my code. I have indicated it above. The file opens but unable to retrieve data.

Comment: A your problem is you're unable to complete the path of your file. You should include the full file path as filename `e.g. C:\Users\User\TestFolder\Orders.xlsx`

Comment: The file actually opens. as it file path was name before. However, I am unable do the rest with the code above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer is based on items 1 and 2 you enumerated above.
I'm not sure what you want to accomplish with the `.Replace` method so I remove it.

```
Sub Consolidate()

Dim wsSource As Worksheet
Dim wbSource As Workbook
Dim wsTarget As Worksheet
Dim wbTarget As Workbook
Dim findRange As Range
Dim lastline As Integer
Dim file As Variant '~~> declared as Variant

Set wbSource = Thisworkbook
Set wsSource = wbSource.Sheets(1) '~~>use index only if you have 1 sheet only

file = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel Files, *.xlsx") '~~> allows you to select the file to load

If file <> False Then
    Set wbTarget = Workbooks.Open(file)
    Set wsTarget = wbTarget.Sheets(1)

    With wsTarget
        lastline = .Range("B"  & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Set findRange = .Range("B1:F" & lastline)
        With findRange
            .Autofilter 1, "New Member"
            .Offset(1,1).Resize(.Rows.Count-1, .Columns.Count-1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy _
            wsSource.Range("B" & wsSource.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1,0)
        End With
    End With
Else
    MsgBox "No file selected. Exiting now." : Exit Sub
End If
wbTarget.Close False
wbSource.Save

End Sub
```

No need to loop through the whole range.
I used `.AutoFilter` method instead.
Hope this is close to what you want.

Comment: Oh Thank you! The autofilter seems better and it does filter the worksheet. However, I am not able to copy and paste the values from wsTarget ("C:F") into wsSource ("B:E"). In this case, there is data in WsSource itself. The data sld appear on the next blank cell and not overwrite. This part doesn't work. I am actually very new to VBA and I am trying to figure some codes myself.

Comment: I referenced it to `Column B`. So it will paste below the last cell in `Column B` with value. Care to check if that is correct?

Comment: Actually the problem is that it's not copying and pasting at all. There is no data received. That makes me lost on the code. Yes, and the reference is correct. It should paste below the last cell in column B.

Comment: It does work on my system. Check whether your sheets are referenced correctly since we used index, to be safe replace it with the actual worksheet names `e.g. wsTarget = wbTarget.Sheets("Sheet1")` Also, check the filter. There should be no leading or trailing spaces in `New Member`. If you can record a macro trying to filter it, that would give you the exact argument for `Criteria1`.

Comment: I managed to tweak them to my file as there are data till the X column. 

.Offset(1, 2).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 4).Select (It works)
.Offset(1, 2).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 4). Copy (It is stuck at J8)
.Offset(1, 2).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1 , 4 ) . SpecialCells (xlCellTypeVisible).Copy _ (Stuck too!)

With wsTarget
        lastline = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Set findRange = .Range("A1:X" & lastline)
        With findRange
            .AutoFilter 2, "New Member"
            .Offset(1, 2).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 4).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy _

Comment: And you're not getting any errors? Try stepping each line then and identify which fails. The problem you described doesn't manifest at my end.

Comment: No. It opens, filters, but data isnt copying.  And it's this line that gives me issues.

'.Offset(1, 2).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 4).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy _
            wsSource.Range("C" & wsSource.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 0)'

Comment: I believe it's >SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy _ wsSource.Range("C" & wsSource.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 0)'

Comment: Thank you so much. I figured out why. The code works just as fine. However it pasted from Row389 - I have resolved this. Thank you so much.

Comment: Ah good. There might be something down below `Column B`. Since the code copy and paste to the last cell in `B`, it paste the information there. Cool! glad you figured it out. Btw, accept answers whenever you are satisfied. You also earn reputation by doing it. :)